# Can arthrogram detect shoulder anomalies that MRI can not?

Tags: mri, orthopedics, rotator-cuff, shoulder

I went to an orthopedic hospital for a pain in my left shoulder since 6 months.
They first did x-ray, and the report was:

> X-ray left shoulder shows reduction in subacromial space and
>   subacromial sclerosis.

Next they did MRI and they didn't see any anomaly.

Can an (invasive) [arthrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthrogram) detect shoulder anomalies that MRI can not?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It is impossible to say over the internet whether a certain diagnostic procedure is necessary in any particular case. However, your other question seems answerable, so I edited out the personalised medical advice part, to make the question more on-topic. If you disagree with the edit, you can always roll back.

Comment: @Lucky: It is ok, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @PillsNPillows : it is *arthrogram*, not *arthogram*.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux, oh, must have been a typo! I'll make sure to change it! I guess you can only do so many "edits" in a certain period of time as it won't let me edit it and fix it right now, but as soon as I can, I'll fix it!! Thanks for pointing it out & I'm sorry!

Comment: @PillsNPillows: It's ok. Thanks for the new tags!